# Getting NotFoundException in Laravel 4

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I am new to Laravel 4. I am trying here is that whenever I click in a link I will go to route, there I will print something. Now one part of the link has to be variable. In the route I want to print the variable.

The code for the link is given below:

```
URL::to("category/{$category}
```

This code in routes.php is

```
Route::get('category/{$c}', function($c){
    return $c;
});
```

It is showing me:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: You need to return a view such as: `return View::make($c);`instead of your echo statement. Have a read of this part of the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/responses

Comment: Route::get('category', function(){
 return 'Here';
});

Comment: @IncitoNetworks, But when I try to add a variable then it is giving me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (`{c}` instead of `{$c}`)

```
Route::get('category/{c}', function($c){
    echo $c;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometime I feel like I am blind!!! Sorry for asking stupid questions.